# Laravel 5 : How to get the value on keyup in edit vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

In our app, we have validation in code.In Edit part, how do I check if the code already exist? when I tried this

**Edit vue**

```
<label>Code</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="edit_code" @keyup="checkCOACode"  v-model="coa_code" v-bind:value="chart_of_account_edit.code">
```

Im encountering this  error

> conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally

**EDIT VUE**

```
 props: {
            chart_of_account_edit: '',
        },
checkCOACode(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var code = this.coa_code;
                const coa = this.$refs.coaCode
                const coaCode = coa.dataset.table
                alert(coaCode);
                return false;
                axios.post("/checkIfCodeExists", {code:code,table:table})
                    .then((response)  =>  {
                        var code_checker = '';
                        if (response.data == 0) {
                            $('.edit-chart-of-account-finish').removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
                            // code_checker    =   'wala pang ganitong code';
                        }else{
                            $('.edit-chart-of-account-finish').attr('disabled','disabled');
                            code_checker    =   'Code is already exist';
                        }
                        this.coa_checker_result = code_checker;
                    });
            },
```

Question: How do I get the input value in my code in Edit Part?

Comment: Do not use both `v-model` and `:value`

Comment: so. how can i get the value? coz im using v-bind=value to get my default value when the user clicked the edit button.

Comment: If you want an initial value set, then set it to `this.coa_code`

Comment: Sorry I dont get it, where should I do that? chart_of_account_edit is my values when I clicked the edit button(I put it in my props). I updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="edit_code" @input="checkCOACode"  v-model="coa_code" v-bind:value="chart_of_account_edit.code">
```

**EDIT**

```
<label>Code</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="edit_code" @keyup="checkCOACode"  v-model="coa_code" v-model:value="chart_of_account_edit.code">
```

Comment: I might be missing what you've changed but how is this any different to what OP already has?

Comment: @Phil looks like `@keyup` became `@input`

Comment: @lagbox cheers. Would help if the author could point that out. I doubt it will change the error message though

Comment: The `@keyup` method i think is responsible for the single key up. example: `@keyup.enter = "checkCOACode" `. The `keyup` event linsener will trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the error you got, you can't have `v-model` and `v-bind:value` in the same element. Try:

```
<label>Code</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="edit_code" @keyup="checkCOACode"  v-model="coa_code">
```

Comment: What will happen to my default value after I click the edit button?

Comment: it will be change, thats what the v-model does. but if you really want to store the initial value, you could add another data to the component like `initial_coa_code` and on `create()/mounted()` do `this.initial_coa_code = this.coa_code`.

Comment: Am I right? In my component i added this initial_coa_code: ' ', in my mounted   this.initial_coa_code = this.coa_code